# Word for "item after next"

Tags: single-word-requests

When I was making a PowerPoint presentation I was directing the reader to the slide after the next one when I realised it sounded incredibly clunky and if there was a specific word for that concept, in the vein of penultimate. This could also be used for items in a list. Example sentence:

> To discover how I coded this program please consult the _______ slide.

Comment: ... the _next-but-one_ slide (or  _next slide but one_)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I would prefer a single word answer (not hypenated) if one exists, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: the post next slide ?

Comment: Interesting question. +1 Until you or someone comes up with that word maybe you could just rearrange the order of the slides so that "next" would work.

Comment: How about the *afternext* slide?

Answer (score 8):

On a different forum someone offered "Postproximate" in response to a similar request. The word doesn't exist right now, but hey, you never know, it might catch on.

Comment: I think it's quite likely there will be a word for this instance, given that there is even a word for the third to last in a sequence and this is definitely a more common scenario.

Comment: Judging by the downvote, yeah, there will be one. Reactionaries resisting change is always a good sign.

Comment: Wasn't my downvote

Comment: @JackGraveney: I know.

Answer (score 6):

***"Subsequent"*** means "to follow" and is commonly used in cases like your example:

> *"To discover how I coded this program please consult the subsequent slide."*

Definition and origin from [MW-O](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/subsequent):

> "following in time, order, or place"
>
> - subsequent events
> - a subsequent clause in the treaty
>
> Origin of SUBSEQUENT
>
> Middle English, from Anglo-French, from Latin subsequent-, subsequens, present participle of subsequi to follow close, from sub- near + sequi to follow — more at sub-, sue
> First Known Use: 15th century

Comment: Subsequent is good for describing any following item/slide but does not directly refer to the item after the next and I would prefer a specific term for this.

Comment: Subsequent is a synonym for next--not the item after the next.

Answer (score 1):

In computer science, I think *next next* is somewhat common, but I don't think it's really used in other applications. However, that might be the most succinct term. Using it for your example, you'd get:

> To discover how I coded this program please consult the next-next slide.

[Other](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/next-next-week-last-last-month.2257751/)  [sites](https://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/139723-In-English-quot-Next-Next-Monday-quot)  [seem](https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-say-previous-previous-and-next-next) to uniformly use the form *X after the next*. For example:

> To discover how I coded this program please consult the slide after the next.

I know this isn't a single word, but seems to be the most accepted usage.

Answer (score 0):

How about "...the second slide following." Truthfully, not every meaning can be captured in a single word.

Answer (score 0):

Once again, not a single word, but baseball fans refer to the next batter as "on deck" and the following batter as "in the hole."

Comment: An interesting option, but probably not one you should use unless you know everyone in the audience is a baseball fan....

Answer (score -1):

I would use "refer" rather than "consult", but either is okay.

To discover how I coded this program please refer to the 2nd slide over.

To discover how I coded this program please refer to the slide after next.

Comment: These have already been covered in other answers.